# a tag not clickable when parent element has negative z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a `z-index: -1` and inside the div there is a div that contains several `a` tags but it is not clickable. I have tried to assign `position:relative`and `z-index:1` to the inner div but it is still not clickable.

[image]

```css
.footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.footer .line {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
...

<div class="footer">
  ...
  <div class="line">
    <a href="">example</a> ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Simply remove the z-index property from .footer class. Then it should work.

Comment: why do you need a negative z-index more to the point (I've never needed one)?  If you explained that, perhaps we can give you a workaround

Comment: @Pete i have added more information to why i need the z-index property

Comment: why not just give the overlap div a higher z-index?

Comment: hmm i thought I tried previously but it didnt work.. but apparently it did work... XD sorry and thanks @Pete problem solved 

Comment: Z-index's work on elements that are on the same stacking context (ie on siblings) so if the overlap div is a child of a div and not on the same level as the footer, you need to work your way up the tree to find it's parent / ancestor that is on the same level as the footer and then apply the higher z-index to that (could be why it didn't work previously)

Comment: Here is a quick exmaple of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/mj076n3o/

Comment: yup got it thanks for your help @Pete

Answer (score 0):

It can't be possible ... If you put negative z-index, it means it's behind the content, it's like if you had someone hidding behind a wall, if you shoot at him, the wall will protect him...

So you tried to put the inner content with positive z-index but if the parent is in negative, all the content will be hide by the "invisible" wall...

You have to put you footer with a **positive or 0 z-index**...

```
.footer{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

=================================

Well in fact there is a way, but It's not good... You could put the inner content in position absolute...

```
.footer .line{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you really need a negative index, is to target all elements inside footer except the ones you want in front for your negative index. It can work depending on what you want, but be cautious that any element not targeted by the rule will go behind if its parent goes behind:

```css
.footer *:not(.front){
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer .front{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    ...
    <p class="line">
        <a class="front" href="">example (behind because of parent)</a><br>
        <a href="">i am behind!</a><br>
        ...
    </p>
    <a class="front" href="">example</a><br>
    ...
</div>
```